# Can I redirect two pages in a single COMMAND?

Tags: redirect, header, location

I want to **redirect *two* pages at once**.

```
if(any statement) {
Header("Location: http://example.com/page.php");
Header("Location: folder/page.php"); } 
else { echo " comment "; }
```

Will this work?
Found a solution see on comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Why on Earth would you want to?  Even if you could, how do you think a browser can display the two pages?  New windows/tabs?  But what if it's a windowless browser (like lynx)?

If you use the above code, PHP will replace the first location header with the second as no headers are actually sent until you start outputting content, after which you cannot call header().

Comment: I have two hosting and want to send some file information when i upload each one to other. Any way?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you want to do.  Can you give a step-by-step sequence of desired events?  If you want to send information to one page from inside PHP, a better solution would be to use the cURL API to contact the page, rather than rely on the user's browser to do it for you (sorry if I've misunderstood what you want to do).

Comment: Hey Dear, I think a way kindly read and comments.. Site-"A" and Site-"B" is two separate domain.  If i send a GET header from Site-"A" to Site-"B" when submit form, and again send GET data from Site-"B" to Site"A" when complete script in page"B". In Site-"A"`<form action="site-B.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" name="rate" value="Rate"></form>` In Site-"B"`Header("Location: http://site-A.com/pageA.php?stat=complete&url=file/link.php");`  Kindly Check this.

Comment: Yes, this will work fine.

However, there is a small disadvantage in that the user's client is still having to make two requests.  If all site-B is doing is processing some data and never sending content to the user, then a nicer method would be to get Site-A to send the data to Site-B behind the scenes.  So in Site-A: `<form action="site-a-page.php><--...-->`, then in the script that handles the form (still on Site-A): `$curl = curl_init("http://Site-B.com/data-handler.php?data=value"); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); curl_exec($curl); /* Now send output to the user */`